# getting the array elements out in new array

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

My project wants to look at the array and get out every two neighbors members together in just one element in the new array. I tried to do that in 2 different ways but all of them didn't work well, I can't find the reason.

```
public static void DviderWords() 
{
    string str = "Alameer Ahmed Amr Ali alameer .";
    string[] oops = str.Split(' ', ',', '!');
    int stringCounter = oops.Length;
    string[] holder = new string[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringCounter; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j > i; i--)
        {
            string newVarible = oops[0+i] + oops[1+i];
            holder[i] = newVarible; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please show the expected result

Comment: Can you provide the expected output of this method?

Comment: if you consider the coming line an array so it must be 
{AlameerAhmed , AhmedAmr , AmrAli , Alialameer}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this.  You only need the one for loop, not two.

```
public static void DviderWords() 
{
    string str = "Alameer Ahmed Amr Ali alameer .";
    string[] oops = str.Split(' ', ',', '!');
    int stringCounter = oops.Length;
    string[] holder = new string[stringCounter - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < stringCounter - 1; i++)
    {
        holder[i] = oops[i] + oops[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working well i have tried this i guess it because the loop pointer can't hold 2 elements together simultaneously !

Comment: Are you aware of the '.' at the end?  When I ran the code, I got the following array ["AlameerAhmed", "AhmedAmr", "AmrAli", "Alialameer", "alameer."].  What is incorrect with this?

Comment: thanks pro. very much 
the error when i print that out , i focus on the old array so i expect that the code is wrong . 
thanks again !

Comment: Please mark the answer as the answer if it is correct.